# Is generator.next() visible in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I have a generator that generates a series, for example:

```
def triangle_nums():
    '''Generates a series of triangle numbers'''
    tn = 0
    counter = 1
    while True:
        tn += counter
        yield tn
        counter += + 1
```

In Python 2 I am able to make the following calls:

```
g = triangle_nums()  # get the generator
g.next()             # get the next value
```

however in Python 3 if I execute the same two lines of code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

but, the loop iterator syntax does work in Python 3

```
for n in triangle_nums():
    if not exit_cond:
       do_something()...
```

I haven't been able to find anything yet that explains this difference in behavior for Python 3.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

`g.next()` has been renamed to `g.__next__()`. The reason for this is consistency: special methods like `__init__()` and `__del__()` all have double underscores (or "dunder" in the current vernacular), and `.next()` was one of the few exceptions to that rule. This was fixed in Python 3.0. [*]

But instead of calling `g.__next__()`, use [`next(g)`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next).

[*] There are other special attributes that have gotten this fix; `func_name`, is now `__name__`, [etc.](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods)

Comment: any idea why python 2 eschewed the dunder convention for these methods in the first place?

Comment: That's probably just an oversight.

Comment: What about when you overwrite __ str __ in classes? Does it change str(obj) or __str__(obj) ?

Comment: @NoName There is no such thing as `__str__(obj)`, so I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro   In `instance1`'s class, I modify `__str__(self)`, in main function, I call `str(instance1)`.

Comment: @NoName Yes, you do.

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice if this change in syntax was documented in PEP 289, where generator expressions are proposed.

Comment: @MatthewMilone It's mentioned in the PEP where the change was proposed, which was five years later. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/

Answer (score 157):

Try:

```
next(g)
```

Check out [this neat table](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#next) that shows the differences in syntax between 2 and 3 when it comes to this.

Comment: @MaikuMori I fixed the link (waiting for peer revision) (The site http://diveintopython3.org seems to be down. Mirror site http://diveintopython3.ep.io is still alive)

Comment: Fixed the link again. http://python3porting.com/differences.html is more complete, btw.

Comment: Is there any justification for the switch from a method to a function, beyond `g.next()` should really be `g.__next__()`, and we need to have something that isn't a dunder method with the functionality of `g.next()`?

Comment: Works for the error ` 'generator' object has no attribute 'next' `.

Answer (score 12):

If your code must run under Python2 and Python3, use the 2to3 [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.next) library like this:

```
import six

six.next(g)  # on PY2K: 'g.next()' and onPY3K: 'next(g)'
```

Comment: There's not much need for this unless you need to support Python versions earlier than 2.6.  Python 2.6 and 2.7 have the `next` built-in function.