# How to get one value at a time from a generator function in Python?

Tags: python, generator

Very basic question - how to get one value from a generator in Python?

So far I found I can get one by writing `gen.next()`. I just want to make sure this is the right way?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Yes, or `next(gen)` in 2.6+.

Comment: I know this is embarrassing by why doesn't this work? `W1 = params.next()` but get an error `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073396/is-generator-next-visible-in-python-3-0

Comment: @CharlieParker You must be using Python 3!

Comment: In Python 3: `W1 = next(params)`

Answer (score 82):

In Python <= 2.5, use `gen.next()`. This will work for all Python 2.x versions, but not Python 3.x

In Python >= 2.6, use `next(gen)`. This is a built in function, and is clearer. It will also work in Python 3.

Both of these end up calling a specially named function, `next()`, which can be overridden by subclassing. In Python 3, however, this function has been renamed to `__next__()`, to be consistent with other special functions.

Answer (score 25):

Use (for python 3)

```
next(generator)
```

Here is an example

```
def fun(x):
    n = 0
    while n < x:
        yield n
        n += 1
z = fun(10)
next(z)
next(z)
```

should print

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 12):

This is the correct way to do it.

You can also use `next(gen)`.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next

Answer (score 5):

To get the value associated with a generator object in python 3 and above use `next(<your generator object>)`.
subsequent calls to next() produces successive object values in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you don't have `gen.next()`, but you still can use `next(gen)`.
A bit bizarre if you ask me but that's how it is.

Comment: It's not that strange. Python 3 is supposed to break things and only allow the clearer better code. Not having backwards compatibility is the point of some breaking changes.