# Retrieving data of generator object for file listing from FTP.mlsd()

Tags: python, ftp

[Python documentation for FTP.mlsd()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd) says that it returns a generator object yielding a tuple. Upon running the following code, I get the address of that object. At this point, I assume that I have successfully received the list from my server as it doesn't pop any error (Please correct me if the assumption is wrong).

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2419770/5460216) suggests that I should use `next()` to get the values in the object. But, upon doing so it shows the error saying `ftplib.error_perm: 501 Option not understood.`

> Code

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('192.168.0.104')
ftp.login('testing','testing')
ftp.cwd('FTP_Test_Site')

temp = ftp.mlsd(path="", facts=["type", "size", "perm"])
print(temp)
print(next(temp))

ftp.quit()
```

> Output

```
<generator object FTP.mlsd at 0x7f46f9438518>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BackUp.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(next(temp))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 589, in mlsd
    self.sendcmd("OPTS MLST " + ";".join(facts) + ";")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 272, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 245, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 501 Option not understood.
```

Any idea about where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ftp mlsd is a generator. So you have to loop over the mlsd.

eg:

```
dirs=[]
nondirs=[]
for item in ftp.mlsd(dir):
    if item[1]['type'] == 'dir':
        dirs.append(item[0])
    else:
        nondirs.append(item[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert into a list:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('192.168.0.104')
ftp.login('testing','testing')
ftp.cwd('FTP_Test_Site')

myList = list(ftp.mlsd(path="", facts=["type", "size", "perm"]))
for item in myList:
   print(item)

ftp.quit()
```