# Keras flow_from_directory class index

Tags: keras

I used to make it manually, but i am using now flow_from_directory to train my network with my own data. I just have one question. When i make model.predict(), how can i know that my index 0 on predictions is for label category dog and index 1 is for category cats?

The code i am using is the following.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_images_path,  
        target_size=(64, 64),  
        batch_size=batch_size)  


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validate_images_path,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=batch_size)
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=1700,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=[early_stopping],
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=196
)
```

What i wanted to know is the pair images vs ground truth label.

Thank you

Comment: Flow_from directory is a convenient method that you just pass the directory and it will generate the correct representation to keras abstracting you the inner processes like getting the raw pixels to numpy array, generate labels etc.

Comment: Don´t know why the downvote. Maybe who downvoted can explain to me this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can have the the index of each class generated by the generator with class_indices property.

```
print(validation_generator.class_indices)
```

Simple...

Comment: Very cool ! In my case it looks like it takes the folders names in alphabetical order.

Comment: Is this deterministic? Will i get the same ordering every run. If it is alphanumerically sorted will the ordering be the same on different operating systems?

Comment: I can't answer it since i have never played with keras agang (since 2017).

Comment: @LeonardFeehan It is documented that they are sorted alphanumerically, so I'd say you can rely on it being deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

When you gather data, you define that. There is no rule. But a simple way to check is:

- see what your first training image is, look at it yourself: is it a cat or a dog?
- then see the training Y (result/class/desired output), is it [0,1] or [1,0]?

This will answer your question.

For getting one sample from a generator, you can see this question: [How to get one value from a generator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419770/how-to-get-one-value-from-a-generator-in-python)

As defined in [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/), the generator output is a tuple of (inputs, targets)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but that is not the way flow_from_directory works. I guess you never used it before?!?!

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to get X and Y values from the flow_from_directory  generator?

Comment: I see. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419770/how-to-get-one-value-from-a-generator-in-python) helps? (Updated the answer).

Comment: The output of what? The fit_generator output one History object. flow_from_directory does not return anything according to docs.

Comment: It's in keras documentation. A generator passed to "fit_generator" must yield a tuple with (inputs,targets). If it doesn't you simply won't be able to train it.

Comment: Yes. Dispite you have not answered my question, you pointed me to the right direction. You can print the generator classes (validation_generator.class_indices) and it´s indexes. I will start coding on one IDE for Python to hit ctrl + space.

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty simple. When you pre-process your data, just replace the class labels with some specific integers (you can call it id). So, when you compute the loss or accuracy from the model's output, just compare the prediction with the ground truth in terms of integer labels (id).

In case if you need the label text, you can get it back from the id (integer).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. If you do it manually, converting the image to numpy arrays and so one. It is the way you say it. If you just pass directories to flow_from_directory it is diferent.  My guess is that you have never used flow_from_directory.