# keras datagen.flow_from_directory class mode categorical get labels wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have training dataset of images for 24 class each class has 2800 image 
the classes are separated one from each other in directory all in one directory called training

i used the following code to load the data using keras :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255
                             ,fill_mode='nearest')

train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory('training-images',class_mode='categorical',
                                         target_size=(32,32))
```

it load the images but the images get the wrong label

the directory structure as follows :

```
training-images/
  0/
     image.jpg
     .
     .
  1/
     image.jpg
     .
     .
  .
  .
  23/
     image.jpg
     .
     .
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong label"? Can you give a specific example of an image, the label you expect, the label you get, and how you obtained that label?

Comment: for a folder named 10 it gives it label 2 and for label named 11 it gives label 3 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flow_from_directory` orders the classes alphabetically, not numerically. This means that your classes will be ordered 0, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. If I were you, I would give the folders descriptive names (e.g. for CIFAR10, they would be "airplane", "bird", etc.), and then map the generated IDs to the class names using [`.class_indices`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43813393/2846923).