# How can I edit a string that was printed to stdout?

Tags: python, printing

How can I edit a string that I just printed? For example, for a countdown counter (First prints 30, then changes it to 29 and so on)

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a variant on the [spinning cursor problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor-using-python).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Print a carriage return `\r` and it will take the cursor back to the beginning on the line. Ensure you don't print a newline `\n` at the end, because you can't backtrack lines. This means you have have to do something like:

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write('29 seconds remaining')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\r28 seconds remaining')
```

(As opposed to using `print`, which *does* add a newline to the end of what it writes to `stdout`.)

Comment: In Python 3 you can use the end parameter to ensure no newline is added at the end: `print(x, end="")`

Comment: Before Python 3 you can leave a `,` after a `print` statement to ensure no newline is added at the end: `print x,`

Comment: I copied that code directly and it prints on a new line in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting Unix/Linux then "curses" makes writing console programs really easy. It handles color, cursor positioning etc. Check out the python wrapper:
http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a xterm-like output device, the way you do this is by OVERWRITING the output.  You have to ensure that when you write the number you end with a carriage-return (without a newline), which moves the cursor back to the start of the line without advancing to the next line.  The next output you write will replace the current displayed number.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change what you printed. What's printed is printed. But, like bradley.ayers said you can return to the beginning of the line and print something new over the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html)** module, which can also provide [customized completion](http://effbot.org/librarybook/readline.htm) and [command history](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#example).