# Making Python text green and using Spinning cursor - Newbies questions

Tags: linux, multithreading, python-2.7, time, subprocess

I want to make my Python script file,when I "announce" something to the user, to be green like this:

[image: TakenfromDyMerge]

How can this be done?I saw a script using this with sys.stdout.write but I dont understand how to use it, Im using a simple "print" commands..

Also, I would like to have the Spinning cursor spin as long as this command runs and only stops when this command stops(finishes):

`print('running network scan')
output = subprocesss.check_output('nmap -sL 192.168.1.0/24',shell=True)
print('Done')`

Any way to do that (unknown time until task is done)?

Im using a code suggested by [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) here:
[Spinning Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995896/7340447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, about getting the terminal color to be green, there is a neat package called [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) that generally works great for me. To check whether the process is running or not, I would recommend using `Popen` instead of `check_output`, since the latter does not allow you to communicate with the process as far as I know. But you need to since you want to know if your subprocess is still running. Here is a little code example that should get you running:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import time
import sys
import colorama

def spinning_cursor():

    """Spinner taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor-using-python/4995896#4995896."""

    while True:
        for cursor in '|/-\\':
             yield cursor

# Create spinner
spinner = spinning_cursor()

# Print and change color to green
print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'running network scan')

# Define command we want to run
cmd = 'your command goes here'

# Split args for POpen
args=shlex.split(cmd)

# Create subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Check if process is still running
while p.poll()==None:

    # Print spinner
    sys.stdout.write(spinner.next())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('\b')

print('Done')

# Grab output
output=p.communicate()[0]

# Reset color (otherwise your terminal is green)
print(colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
```