# Print to same line in console, over previous text, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried all the scripts mentioned in other questions, but not working for me.

```
for x in range (0,10):
    print(x, end='\r', flush=True)
    print(x, sep='\r', end='', flush=True)
    print('\r', x)
```

Please help on this.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: @dirtybit, It should print on same place, For me printing like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, I want to overwrite in same place, at last 9 should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you want a `time.sleep(1)` to have a better visualization, using `stdout.write`:

```
import sys
import time
for i in range(5):
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will check from Terminal, Python basic IDLE not happening.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to overwrite the text, right?

You need to write backspaces to delete the last line and then print the next one.
Check out this post for an example: [How to create a spinning command line cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor)

Comment: Yes want to overwrite

Comment: Please not that if you want to see the text get overwritten you'll probably need to add some delay in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...  print('\r', x, end='')
... 
 9>>>
```

As you can see, all the other numbers got overwritten because to the carriage-return symbol `\r`.

Comment: For me printing like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, I want to overwrite

Comment: @SPy, where are you running this? it seems like your terminal doesn't support the carriage-return symbol. Try to run this in a regular terminal provided by your OS.

Comment: Running in Python IDLE

Comment: @SPy, well, that's the problem. Run this in a normal terminal instead.

Comment: Thanks, will check from Terminal