# How to change while True to while False in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I was trying to create a spinning slash [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor) when it got to me thinking, "What the? What should I do?" about this code.

```
def stat():
    if True:
        driver.get(webs)
        return False


def spin():
    def spinning_cursor():
        while True:
            for cursor in '|/-\\':
                yield cursor

    spinner = spinning_cursor()
    while stat():
        sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\b')

def catch(xpath=xpaths, image_name=image_names):
    try:
        print('Initializing Chrome: ', end="")
        global driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        spin()
```

In function `spin()`; `while stat()` I want it to be true, then when `stat()` finished, I want it to return false so that `spin()` would stop and `catch()` would continue

Comment: Can't you just use "not" operator?

Comment: Side point: `if True:` is always true.

Comment: Welcome to the world of multithreading

Comment: Bug is: `while stat()` always returns `False`. A true answer to this question would point to this, and Python's [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this:

```py
def stat():
    if driver.get(webs):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def spin():
    def spinning_cursor():
        while True:
            for cursor in '|/-\\':
                yield cursor

    spinner = spinning_cursor()
    while stat():
        sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\b')
```

The `stat()` function is a more explicit evaluation of Python's [if expression evaluation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if).

This means the `stat()` function can be replaced with a call to `driver.get(webs)` in the `if` expression:

```py
def spin():
    def spinning_cursor():
        while True:
            for cursor in '|/-\\':
                yield cursor

    spinner = spinning_cursor()
    while driver.get(webs):
        sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\b')
```

Comment: `is_state_called` is used instead of `is_stat_called`

Comment: @kivanc it works changing `is_state_called = stat()` to `is_stat_called = stat()`

Comment: this still shouldn't work, `stat()` always returns true, unless `driver.get()` short circuits out somehow

Comment: Thanks @matthew for improving the answer. Honestly, I don't know anything about the functionality of **driver** (driver = webdriver.Chrome()), thus I didn't know what it returns.

Comment: @matthew I just realize that it can't stdout the spin due to the fact that it can't handle two process running both at the same time; the stdout and selenium. ;(