# I want to do a bar that rotate in python

Tags: python

I want to do a bar that rotate in python, like that |/-|-| ..... but in the same line , to make a ilusion that it's rotating, I have been looking for fews solutions , I'm a begginer in python and I tried like that:

```py
from time import sleep

barras = ["|","/","-","\\","|"]
for c in barras:
    sleep(1)
    print(c,end="".replace(c,c))`
```

Comment: Consider checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor)

Comment: `I tried like that` ... and what happened?