Adding a spinner while waiting for new line streaming from subprocess
I'm currently writing a little python tool that executes a program through subprocess.Popen(), which works very well. The subprocess takes a long time to run and sporadically outputs stdout_lines to indicate milestones, which i effectively stream back to print from the python script using toklands approach in xref:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417735 which is absolutely beautiful. The issue is that it sometimes takes several hours in between outputs, and I would like to have an indicator that the subprocess is still alive. So I was thinking of implementing a spinner, à la xref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995896/24139037 . The issue is that I cannot wrap my head around how toklands generative/iter/yield stdout_line works in the first place, so I am unable to effectively incorporate the spinner. Other threads havn't been helpful to my understanding of this.
Code References:
Toklands std_out stream:
import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)


##  START MAXQUANT
print(' ##  MaxQuant:\n')
# Run!
for path in execute(command):
    print(path, end="")

Spinner:
import sys
import time

def spinning_cursor():
    while True:
        for cursor in '|/-\\':
            yield cursor
spinner = spinning_cursor()

for _ in range(50):
    sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')

I tried placing the spinner at different positions, both in the execute definition as well as in the actual execution for-loop. I think the main issue is that I don't even know what it is that I don't understand, so I feel lost :D reading on the topic didn't help much, so pointers to appropriate literature are very much appreciated.
