# next() method in Python file object

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a file object and try to access the next() on it. But the interpreter throws error mentioning that the function does not exist.

```
open("scala.txt").next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

But many discussions that I come across, mention that next() is available. But when I use this object in a for loop, it works fine. Can I get some help on why the above piece of code throws error.

PS: I encounter similar context when I create my own generator & try to invoke next(). When I place the generator object in a for loop, it works nicely.

```
>>> x = (e for e in range(1,10))
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `next(foo)` instead. The syntax changed in python 3.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073396/is-generator-next-visible-in-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` is a built-in function, not a bound method. Example:

```
next(open("scala.txt"))

x = (e for e in range(1, 10))
next(x)
```

Behind-the-scenes, calling `next()` on an object tends to call the bound (but hidden) method `__next__()`, which does exactly what you think it does.

Comment: ah, thanks much!! This helps me a a lot!